# Strategy pattern in functional programming

Tags: functional-programming, kdb, strategy-pattern

I am trying to write a Strategy design pattern example in the functional programming language ( not purely functional, no objects, no function overloading) using the example mentioned on [Java DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-strategy).

Though I understand that a lot of functionality comes out of the box in the functional programming language.

Am I missing anything here in terms of the design pattern concept?

`:` is the assignment operator.

**File FileCompressor**

```
strategy:`noOp;

setCompressionAlgo:{[algo]
    strategy:algo
}

compressFiles:{[filesList]
    strategy[filesList]
 }
```

**File ZipCompressor**

```
zipCompress:{[fileList]
  //compress each file using the zip compression
 }
```

**File RarCompressor**

```
rarCompress:{[fileList]
  //compress each file using the rar compression
 }
```

**File Client**

```
start:{[path]
    filesList:getFiles[path];
    setCompressionAlgo[zipCompress];
    compressFiles[fileList]
 }
```

Comment: "*the functional programming language*" - which language are you talking about? Can you link an explanation of that syntax? The question is really hard to answer if you use a language that noone else does.

Comment: here is the link - https://code.kx.com/q/tutorials/q-for-all/ & https://code.kx.com/q/tutorials/q-by-examples/#user-defined-functions-and-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually wouldn't make the strategy a global (mutable) variable. You can simplify your example to

```
start: {[path]
    compressFiles: zipCompress;
    // change to
    // compressFiles: rarCompress
    // to use a different strategy

    // apply the strategy:
    compressFiles[fileList1]
    compressFiles[fileList2]
}
```